# How to securely let a Salesforce user automatically log into my site

Tags: authentication, salesforce

I have a SaaS which integrates with SalesForce. I have synced all the SF users to my database so that my local users have a SF user ID stored.

I need to have a custom link in SF which will bring the user to my site and log them in automatically. The wrong way to do this is to pass the SF user ID in the link and simply match the SF User ID to the one I've stored in the database. What is the right way to ensure the referred SF user should be authorized? Is there some token I can put in the link from SF that I can then verify against the SF API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches for this:

1. Create a canvas app that sends a signed request to your site. The signed request will include the current users session details. You can use these to verify that the user is indeed who they say they are. I.e. They haven't just made up an id and that they came from an active Salesforce session. See [Verifying and Decoding a Signed Request](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_app_unsigning_code_example.htm). The advantage of this approach is that you can verify the request has been signed with your apps consumer secret.
2. Its an older approach that isn't really promoted by Salesforce any more as the canvas apps superseded it. Create what was known as a composite app. This was basically an iframe to your external site that could include the session id and server url in the query string (over SSL). With these details you could call back into Salesforce and get the User Id of the session owner.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.